# Is there a specific name for the line commonly drawn under arithmetic problems?

Tags: word-choice

Basic problems are often written as:

3
-2
--      <-- Is there a name for this?
 1

Comment: All things considered, most things don't have names. For example, is there a name for the choice of using a column to indicate addition instead of a row (3 + -2 = 1)? Also, there are many things that we are familiar with that have names, but we (i.e., most people) don't know. For example, do you know the name of the bone from your elbow to your wrist? Neither do I.

Comment: I know this is not the point, but there are two bones in the forearm, and they are called the radius and the ulna. Doesn't every schoolchild learn that in basic biology?

Comment: The line, and it's the same as the equals sign =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An *underline*. See “[Addition: Notation and terminology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition#Notation_and_terminology)” at *Wikipedia*.

Comment: Although I believe it to be a technicality, as it appears that the answer is that there is no given name specific to this item, given the specific wikipedia reference that only uses the word _underline_, I am going to mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You may use  **vinculum** or **horizontal line**  in mathematical notation. Please check [Mathforum](https://web.archive.org/web/20180119061901/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/58409.html) and [Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics))

Comment: Vinculum appears to be only for division and repeat grouping notation, but thank you for teaching me a new word.

Answer (score 0):

I think "the equals line" would be understood if that's all you need (and if you can't come up with something better).